# Discord.js dispatcher dont emit start event

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I see some very stranger issue where dispatcher event "start" dont emit. Here code to play function:

```js
let play = async (url, message) => {
    await message.member.voice.channel.join().then(connection => {
        let dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(url, {
            quality: 'highestaudio',
            highWaterMark: 1024 * 1024 * 10
        }))
        .on('start', () => {
            message.channel.send('Play started');
            dispatcher.setVolume(1);
        })
        .on('finish', () => {
            message.channel.send('Play finished');
            message.member.voice.channel.leave();
        })
        .on('error', e => {
            message.channel.send('Cannot play song');
            console.error(e);
            return message.member.voice.channel.leave();
          });
    });
}
```

The finish event is emits properly and bot disconnect from voice channel. **But he doing its instant after joining**. As expected on dispathcer ends i see message about finishing.
Strange fact is that nothing being played and i dont see message about starting.
And error event dont emits, its not about link issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbldZ.png

I also tried many diffrent types of streaming audio, libs and encoding, but nothing changes. Yes, i tried diffrent videos(Shorter | longer).

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. When I try your code the message gets send, the music starts and everything is working. Are you sure you don't get any errors?

Comment: I'm guessing this could be a issue with ffmpeg. Do you have it correctly installed?